# Running a python script on time machine to copy files

Tags: python, macos, permission-denied, file-access

I want to get rid of all the data in my time machine backup drive and only keep the photos. So I have written a python script for that which walks through files, finds out the photos ('png', 'jpg', etc.) and then copies those to another folder on the desktop.

The problem is osx doesn't allow the script to access files in that drive. This is my script:

```py
from os import path, getcwd, mkdir, walk
from shutil import copy2, copyfile

def klasorleri_gez(kynk, hdf):
    butun_icerik = walk(kynk, False)
    butun_icerik_liste = [i for i in butun_icerik]

    for i in range(len(butun_icerik_liste)):
        klasor = butun_icerik_liste[i]
        klasor_adresi = klasor[0]
        klasordeki_dosyalar = klasor[2]
        for dosya in klasordeki_dosyalar:
            dosya_adress = path.join(klasor_adresi, dosya)
            if '.jpg' in dosya_adress or '.png' in dosya_adress or '.jpeg' in dosya_adress:
                print('Kopyalaniyor: ', dosya_adress)
                copy2(dosya_adress, hdf)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    HEDEF_KLASOR_ISIM = 'hedef_klasor'
    KAYNAK_KLASOR_ISIM = "/Volumes/Time{}Machine/Backups.backupdb/Kerem’s{}MacBook{}Pro{}(2)/".format(" ", " ", " ", " ")

    cwd = getcwd()
    hedef_klasor = path.join(cwd, HEDEF_KLASOR_ISIM)
    mkdir(hedef_klasor)
    klasorleri_gez(KAYNAK_KLASOR_ISIM, HEDEF_KLASOR_ISIM)
```

I have already tried to run it with `sudo`, `sudo su` and as a super user it's still not permitted. In [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/162690/how-can-i-delete-time-machine-files-using-the-commandline) and [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130827090641/http://techjournal.318.com/general-technology/the-time-machine-safety-net/) it is mentioned that you can run a command with arguments using `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass`, so I have run the following command:

```
Kerems-MacBook-Pro:Desktop base$ /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass ls /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/Kerem’s\ MacBook\ Pro\ \(2\)/
ls: : Operation not permitted
```

And still no luck! Does anybody know how to overcome that permission issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to get TimeMachine to restore the files to the desired location.

Comment: @martineau Maybe, but I want to delete everything apart from photos (pngs and jpgs), so some 'custom file restoration' is needed.